# Data transfer between two kerberos secured cluster

Tags: security, hadoop, hdfs, bigdata, kerberos

I am trying to transfer data between two secured **kerberos**. Cluster. I am facing issue that I have no config change access to source cluster I need to change everything on destination cluster. Is any way that I can setup trust realm between both the cluster without edit any config on source cluster.

Comment: What KDC is used by the clusters?

Comment: i ma using MIT KDC

Answer (score 0):

If you are using distcp, then you will have to make sure both the clusters KDC know each other, by editing krb5.conf to add [realms] and [domain_realms] on each cluster to know about the other cluster as follows:

```
[realms]
        <CLUSTER2_REALM> = {
                kdc = <cluster2_server_kdc_host>:88
                admin_server = <cluster2_server_kdc_host>:749
                default_domain = <cluster2_host>
        }
[domain_realm]
        Clustre2_NN1 = CLUSTER2_REALM
        Cluster2_NN2= CLUSTER2_REALM
```

Similarly on cluster2 as well, with CLUSTER1 details.

Then you need to create principals on both the clusters

```
addprinc -e "aes128-cts-hmac-sha1-96:normal aes256-cts-hmac-sha1-96:normal" krbtgt/<CLUSTER1_REASLM>@<CLUSTER2_REALMS>

modprinc -maxrenewlife <n>day krbtgt/<CLUSTER1_REALM>@<CLUSTER2_REALM>
```

## Below properties needs to be set for hadoop.security.auth_to_local

```
In Cluster1:
RULE:[1:$1@$0](.*@\Q<CLUSTER2_REALM>\E$)s/@\Q<CLUSTER2_REALM>\E$//
RULE:[2:$1@$0](.*@\Q<CLUSTER2_REALM>\E$)s/@\Q<CLUSTER2_REALM>\E$//
In Cluster2:
RULE:[1:$1@$0](.*@\Q<CLUSTER1_REALM>\E$)s/@\Q<CLUSTER1_REALM>\E$//
RULE:[2:$1@$0](.*@\Q<CLUSTER1_REALM>\E$)s/@\Q<CLUSTER1_REALM>\E$//
```

## Restart kdc

```
/etc/init.d/krb5kdc stop
/etc/init.d/kadmin stop
/etc/init.d/krb5kdc start
/etc/init.d/kadmin start
```

## Failover or Restart Namenodes